# Report Viewer Configuration Error

Tags: sharepoint, reportviewer

I want to display report inside of SharePoint. My ASPX page contains one `Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms.ReportViewer` control. When I try to open this page, I get error:

> Report Viewer Configuration Error
>
> The Report Viewer Web Control HTTP Handler has not been registered in the application's web.config file. Add <add verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" 
>   type = "Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" /> to the system.web/httpHandlers section of the web.config file, or add <add name="ReportViewerWebControlHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" /> to the system.webServer/handlers section for Internet Information Services 7 or later.
>
> The attempt to connect to the report server failed. Check your connection information and that the report server is a compatible version.
>
> Client found response content type of 'text/html; charset=utf-8', but expected 'text/xml'. The request failed with the error message: -- 401 UNAUTHORIZED<RSError xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/sql/reportingservices"><MoreInformation><Message>Unbekannter Fehler beim Reporting Services-Endpunkt für diese SharePoint-Website. Wenden Sie sich an den Administrator der SharePoint-Website.</Message></MoreInformation></RSError> --.

Do I indeed need to add this section to web.config? And where should I add this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to add the following sections,

```
<add verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" type = "Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
```

to `system.web` in section `handlers`

and add the following sections

```
<add name="ReportViewerWebControlHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
```

to `system.webserver` in section `handlers`

Actually the error message explains everything! Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

This the complete web.config after I solve this issue:

```html
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
 <system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />
    </httpHandlers>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <defaultDocument>
      <files>
        <add value="PreviewReport.aspx" />
      </files>
    </defaultDocument>
    <handlers>
      <add name="ReportViewerWebControlHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

thanks .
I use godaddy with a shared host and this solution work for my aplication thanks a lot.

```
<system.webServer>
<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
<handlers>

    <add name="ReportViewerWebControlHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />

</handlers>
</system.webServer>
```